# How do I fix undefined control sequence for \maketitle?

Tags: titles, report, undefined

Here is my code, the ucscthesisbs document class is a template from my professor and has not caused any issues in the past, I'm not sure how to include it in this question because it is too long to copy paste, here is a link: [document class](https://www.overleaf.com/project/6554026f9f2f08f5558fcffc). Here is the error message:

\AB@maketitle ...uppercase \expandafter {@campus
}} \par \bigskip {\bfserie...
l.19 \maketitle

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[image: title error message] [image: title error]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{ucscthesisbs}
\bibliographystyle{apalike3.bst}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\title{Optical Tweezers}
\author{Aila}
\affil{Rebecca, Aidan}

\maketitle

\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
The basic principle behind optical tweezers is that the forces exerted by a laser can manipulate small objects. In this experiment we recorded the interactions and movements of a 0.99 $\mu m$ and 1.99 $\mu m$ diameter bead sample with a L658P040 laser diode. 


\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's a private class you have not provided nor have you shown the error that you got so it will b ealmost impossible to help

Comment: no latex document written since the 1980s should be using `epsf` package. Are you really using that????

Comment: Can you show the whole error message?

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{apalike3.bst}` should not have `.bst` in the argument

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what should I use that's similar to epsf? I copied it from an older lab report. Also how could I share the class?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added an image of the error message.

Comment: I would assume you are not using the package and can simply delete it from the `\usepckage`

Comment: The image contains no information it just says undefined. Post the actual error message from the log file, as text, in a code block, that will say which command is undefined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the error and linked the whole document so that the class can be seen.

Comment: so as you see the error is `\@campus` is undefined (as you have not used `\campus` as shown by SamCarter

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your class is the same as found at https://github.com/rschroder/ice_giant_thermal_evolution_thesis/tree/master , then it requires the macros

- `\campus`
- `\degree`
- `\field`
- `\degreemonth`
- `\degreeyear`

before you can use `\maketitle`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{ucscthesisbs}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{Optical Tweezers}
\author{Aila}
\affil{Rebecca, Aidan}
\campus{quack}
\degree{quack}
\field{quack}
\degreemonth{quack}
\degreeyear{quack}

\maketitle

\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
The basic principle behind optical tweezers is that the forces exerted by a laser can manipulate small objects. In this experiment we recorded the interactions and movements of a 0.99 $\mu m$ and 1.99 $\mu m$ diameter bead sample with a L658P040 laser diode. 
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked to get rid of the error message but the title, author etc still repeats itself at the top of my abstract. I added more info into the question if you don't mind helping a bit more. Thank you so so much

Comment: @Aila That's how your class defines the `abstract` environment

Comment: oh i see, thank you